# Windows XP: the application failed to initialize properly (0xc0000005) error for my MFC app

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-c++, mfc, windows-xp, access-violation

I have a mfc dialog based installer. Its running fine on every OS except Windows XP where it just doesn't initiate and gives this error. [image]

I already have C++ Runtime environment installed on that machine.

What may be the cause of this error? Do I need to change some project properties from Visual Studio?
How do I solve it ?
Thanks.

Comment: Time to fire up a debugger.

Comment: Or see if there's any info in the Event Log (Application/System)

Answer (score 0):

Use Depends.exe (a tool you can find on the internet) to see which DLLs your exe needs. It is likely that you need to provide some of those DLLs with your installer.